# Що означає прислів'я "нате і мій глек на капусту, щоб і я була Химка."

Tags: фразеологізми

Слухав [бесіду з пані Забужко](https://youtu.be/S--4oklQiQE?si=mThvuxIhf1vk0c2E&t=2585) і вона казали, що соцмережі зроблені для того, щоб кожен кидав свій глек на капусту. Почав шукати значення виразу і знайшов таке:

> втручатися
>
> Встрявати (в щось), влазити, вмішуватися, залазити, лізти, мішатися, потикатися, присерблюватися, присусіджуватися, пхатися, рипатися, соватися, сунутися, тикатися, тицятися, ув'язуватися
>
> **Фразеологічні синоніми:** встромляти носа; встромляти носа в чуже просо; встромляти свій писок; втручатись у внутрішні справи; заглядати в чужі горшки; залазити в душу; лізти в душу; лізти в чужий горох; лізти з чобітьми в душу; лізти, куди не слід; лізти нахрапом; лізти не в своє; лізти не в своє діло; лізти рахма; ніс сувати; носа встромляти; потикати носа; пхати носа; пришивати пришви (втручатися в розмову); рипатися в чужі двері; совати носа в чуже просо; совати свого носа; совати свого носа в чужий город; совати свого носа в чужі горшки; соватись у чужий монастир; сувати носа; сунути носа; сунути носа, куди не слід; сунути свого носа; сунутися з своїми козами на торг; тикати носа; тикати свого носа в чуже просо; тикати свого носа в чужий город; тикатись у чужі справи; тицяти носа
>
> **Приповідки:** Нате вам п'ятака, прийміть мене, штурпака. Нате й мій гріш на ладан, щоб і моє перед Богом курилось. Нате й мій галун до церкви. Нате й мій стовбун, щоб і я там був. Нате й мій гріш та купите дьогтю, бо в мене паршива голова. Нате й мій глек на капусту. *Нате й мій глек на капусту, щоб і я була Вівдя (Гапка, Настя, Пріська, Риндя, Химка, Хівря).* Нате й мій глек на сироватку, щоб і моя була масниця. Нате й моїх п'ять, щоб було десять. Нате й мої штани в жлукто, нехай визоляться
>
> Застереження тим, хто втручається: Без тебе вода не освятиться! Твій номер восьмий. Не до тебе п'ють. Не до тебе п'ють, не кричи "будь здоров." Не до тебе п'ється. Не твоє діло. Не твого ума діло. Не твоя копа молотиться. Не твоє засипано. Не мішайся в чужі лика!
>
> <sub>[Словник синонімів Вусика](https://slovnyk.me/dict/synonyms_vusyk/%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)</sub>

Здається зі загальним значенням виразу зрозуміло, але що означає його друга частина *щоб і я була ...*?